# Check the specific attribute of a html tag exists in Capybara with polling

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, capybara

I have this simple HTML. Those attributes of buttons (Such as "AAAAA") will transit per external events. The realtime-update is executed by AJAX pooling.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="group"><button title="AAAAA"/></div>
<div class="group"><button title="BBBBB"/></div>
<div class="group"><button title="CCCCC"/></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
...
</div>
```

Let's assume "AAAAA" will transit to "DDDDD" after XXX event. The test script would be like...

```
scenario 'test' do
    # Before change
    page.within(first('.parent')) do
        page.within(all('.group')[0]) do
            expect(page.find('button')[:title]).to include('AAAAA')
        end
        page.within(all('.group')[1]) do
            expect(page.find('button')[:title]).to include('BBBBB')
        end
        page.within(all('.group')[2]) do
            expect(page.find('button')[:title]).to include('CCCCC')
        end
    end

    XXX

    # After change (AJAX polling)
    page.within(first('.parent')) do
        page.within(all('.group')[0]) do
            expect(page.find('button')[:title]).to include('DDDDD')
        end
    end 
end
```

However, this doesn't work. Because `expect(page.find('button')[:title]).to include('DDDDD')` won't wait until the AJAX polling executed. If I put `sleep(20)` after `XXX`, this test worked, however, that is not Capybara way, I guess.

I'd like to know the smart way to handle this situation properly.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Capybara provided matchers, which have waiting/retrying behavior built-in, rather than the RSpec provided`include`

```
expect(page).to have_css("button[title='DDDDDD']")
```

if you want it to test for substrings in title, instead of equality, you can use `*=` rather than `=`, etc.

You should also prefer unique css selectors like `find('.group:nth-of-type(1)')` rather than `all('.group')[0]` whenever possible (the meanings of those two expressions are slightly different, so sommetimes it may not be posssible) since elements returned from all/first are non-reloadable